# Asymmetric slicing python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, slice, dask

Consider the following matrix:

```
X = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
     array([[0, 1, 2],
            [3, 4, 5],
            [6, 7, 8]])
```

Let say I want to subset the following array

```
array([[0, 4, 2],
       [3, 7, 5]])
```

It is possible with some indexing of rows and columns, for instance

```
col=[0,1,2] 
row = [[0,1],[1,2],[0,1]]
```

Then if I store the result in a variable array I can do it with the following code:

```
array=np.zeros([2,3],dtype='int64')
for i in range(3):
    array[:,i]=X[row[i],col[i]]
```

Is there a way to broadcast this kind of operation ? I have to do this as a data cleaning stage for a large file ~ 5 Gb, and I would like to use dask to parallelize it. But in a first time if I could avoid using a for loop I would feel great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For arrays with [`NumPy's advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), it would be -

```
X[row, np.asarray(col)[:,None]].T
```

Sample run -

```
In [9]: X
Out[9]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

In [10]: col=[0,1,2] 
    ...: row = [[0,1],[1,2],[0,1]]

In [11]: X[row, np.asarray(col)[:,None]].T
Out[11]: 
array([[0, 4, 2],
       [3, 7, 5]])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same operation using numpy.take ? I am asking this because dask arrays don't support this kind of fancy indexing but implement a function similar to numpy.take.

Comment: @jmamath You can do : `np.take(X, row*X.shape[1] + col[:,None])` for `row` and `col` as arrays.